# c# add header <p></p> and footer <p></p> tags to html string

Tags: c#, html-parsing

I know html agility pack and some other libraries can do it but I want to avoid these as the requirement is pretty small.

I am thinking:

Find Index of <body>. Insert header just after this.

Find index of </body>. Insert footer just before this.

Not sure if the above will work. Any other ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what the original string looks like and where you want to insert the new tags. Could you please clarify the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work just fine if your `<body>` always looks like that, and not sometimes like `<body class="myclass">`. Otherwise you need a regular expression or something more lightweight (like finding `<body` and then the first `>`.

HTML Agility Pack is in this case an overkill.

Comment: Yea your right. <body and then first > will be required. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is it HTML, or XHTML. If the latter, you could choose to load it into an XML Document, and manipulate it using the standard XML library functions.

Comment: Its XHTML most probably. Will check this out. Thanks.

Comment: But you'll have the problem that if it is malformed, this solution will go down the drain. Furthermore, if it is for something that simple, it might be an overkill.

Comment: @Gideon - Sure, the malformation will affect my soltion, but I would argue that under certain circumstances it could break most solutions. The XML solution, however gives us the ability to catch these issues. And with regard to the 'overkill' argument, if this was actually a pure XML document, then I'm not sure this would have been questioned. If an XML lib is good engough for manipulating and XML document, then it is good enough for manipulating HTML that just happens to be valid XML. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear of your objective, but if you're adding elements to an existing HTML element, you could use jQuery to accomplish this:

```
$("body").prepend("<p>Hello, World!</p>");
$("body").append("<p>Hello, World!</p>");
```